# JibX: how to output the fields from a particular class into different parts of the XML

Tags: java, xml, data-binding

I've managed to get what I want when mapping with inheritance like this:

ThisClassShouldntExist

- freeFlowMsg
- errorMsg

BaseForm **extends** ThisClassShouldntExist

- function
- subFunction

SpecificForm **extends** BaseForm

- address

**My binding.xml:**

```
<binding>
    <mapping class="com.struts.form.ThisClassShouldntExist" abstract="true">
        <value name="free-flow-message" field="freeFlowMessage" />
        <value name="error-msg" field="errorMessage" />
    </mapping>  

    <mapping class="com.struts.form.BaseForm" abstract="true">
        <value name="prog-name" field="function" />
        <value name="sub-prog-name" field="subFunction" />
    </mapping>

    <mapping name="cngaddress" class="com.struts.form.AddressDisplayForm">
        <structure name="header">
            <structure map-as="com.struts.form.BaseForm" usage="optional" />
        </structure>

        <value name="address" field="addressline1" usage="optional"/>

        <structure name="FOOTER">
            <structure map-as="com.struts.form.ThisClassShouldntExist" 
                               usage="optional" />
        </structure>
    </mapping>  
</binding>
```

**A sample data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cngaddress>
  <header>
    <prog-name>prog-name</prog-name>
    <sub-prog-name>sub-prog-name</sub-prog-name>
  </header>
  <address>address</address>
  <FOOTER>
    <free-flow-message>free-flow-message</free-flow-message>
    <error-msg>error-msg</error-msg>
  </FOOTER>
</cngaddress>
```

---

**So, the bottom line is that I need to "split" the output of the class BaseForm into 2 different part of the XML output. First part goes into `<header>`, second into `<footer>`, but also I want to avoid the inheritance just to comply with JibX.**

I tried doing something like this but didn't work:

```
<structure name="FOOTER">
    <structure field="aFieldFromSuperClassBaseForm" 
               map-as="com.struts.form.ThisClassShouldntExist" 
               usage="optional" />
</structure>
```

Also tried to define 2 `<mapping>` in the same binding for the same class, but of course it wouldn't work.